# In R 'factoextra',when i use function 'fviz_eig',how to adjust the column width and label size

Tags: r

In package `factoextra`, when I use the function `fviz_eig`, how to adjust the column width and label size?
("width=0.6,text.size=17" seems can't work, also no error message show)

```
library(factoextra)
data(iris)
res.pca <- prcomp(iris[,-5],scale=TRUE)
fviz_eig(res.pca,addlabels = TRUE,choice = 'eigenvalue',
         ylim=c(0,3),width=0.6,text.size=17)
```

I want to change the text size, which is marked by bursh as below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same with `ggplot` use `theme(text = element_text(size = 10))` to resize label. Use `bar_width` inside `fvie_eig` to change width of bars.

```
fviz_eig(res.pca,addlabels = TRUE,choice = 'eigenvalue',
         ylim=c(0,3),bar_width=0.2) +theme(text = element_text(size = 10))
```

[image]

## Manually

```
fviz_eig(res.pca,choice = 'eigenvalue',
         ylim=c(0,3),bar_width=0.2) + geom_text(label = round(res.pca$sdev^2,1), vjust=-0.4, hjust = 0, size = 5)
```

[image]

Comment: "theme(text = element_text(size = 10))" will change all text size , there is any way only to change the label value ? (just like geom_text(size=10), only change the text for values) . Thanks!

Comment: @anderwyang To only change text for `label`s, use `theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 20))`. But I'm hesitated what are labels.... are they `1,2,3,4` or `Eivenvalue` and `Dimensions`? For `1,2,3, and 4` use `axis.text = element_text(size = 30)` and for `dimensions` and `Eigenvalue`, use `axis.title = element_text(size = 15)`

Comment: thanks for your replay , i edited my question. Maybe that can make it clear.

Comment: @anderwyang To change that text's size, it should be done manually. By adding line `+ geom_text(label = round(res.pca$sdev^2,1), vjust=-0.4, hjust = 0, size = 5)` and remove `addlabels = TRUE` argument in `fviz_eig`. All arguments in `geom_text` is same except `size` with [source code](https://rdrr.io/cran/factoextra/src/R/eigenvalue.R). I edit code and add plot above.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is not clear about the extra arguments.  It just says `...` and to look under the `options` i.e.

> ...   optional arguments to be passed to the function ggpar.

When we check the `ggpar` link

> Use font.x = 14, to change only font size;

If we check the function `fviz_eig`

```
...
    extra_args <- list(...)
    bar_width <- extra_args$bar_width
    linetype <- extra_args$linetype
```

Therefore, instead of `width`, change it to `bar_width` would work.   It is not giving any error because the variadic argument is `...` and anything can be passed as input, but they may not be used within the function as per the `extr_args` extraction with `bar_width` and `linetype` implies

By changing the `bar_width`, was able to change to reproduce the changes in the width.  Also, make use of `label_size`

```
fviz_eig(res.pca,addlabels = TRUE,choice = 'eigenvalue',
          ylim=c(0,3),bar_width=0.3, label_size = 10)
```

-output

[image]
vs

```
fviz_eig(res.pca,addlabels = TRUE,choice = 'eigenvalue',
          ylim=c(0,3),bar_width=0.6, label_size = 17)
```

Comment: when i changge the value of 'label_size', the plot have no any change.